# How to configure log4j.properties for embedded Jetty server?

Tags: log4j, embedded-jetty

Currently working with a web page built to use the embedded Jetty server and unable to modify the code to turn on tracing.

As a result, turning on the tracing is being attempted via log4j.properties but unable to obtain any trace information.

Here is the error attempting to be traced.  (Error occurs within : JspServletWrapper)

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp+        
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:197)+  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)+     
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)+    
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)+   
at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:106)+
```

JETTY_PATH = /usr/jetty_home

In the JETTY_PATH directory, the log4j.properties was created and since the error occurs within the JsServletWrapper, the file contains the following :

Note : Had to use an example from https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-configure-log4j-using-properties-file/ as I haven't previously configured this type of file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, filer

log4j.appender.filer=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.filer.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.filer.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.filer.File=/tmp/tmp/jetty.log
log4j.appender.filer.append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.logger.org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper=DEBUG, filer    <----Class attempting to trace
```

Is the log4j.properties file valid and/or in the correct location?

Is there some other configuration step that required to obtain tracing via the log4j.properties for an embedded Jetty server?

***Edited to add the Juli stuff.***

The logging.properties is placed in the $JETTY_PATH (not sure if correct location)

> cat logging.properties

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /tmp/tmp/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /tmp/tmp/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /tmp/tmp/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /tmp/tmp/logs
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = admin.

5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /tmp/tmp/logs
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].handlers = 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper = FINE   <-----Class attempting to trace.
```

Comment: Apache Jasper (the JSP engine) uses `org.apache.juli.logging` for logging, not log4j.

Comment: Modified the original post to include the Juli stuff from https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/conf/logging.properties.shtml   with some edits.